# How to selectively multiply columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two columns that show how far a bus stop is from a person's house. One is the number and the other the unit (block or minutes). I want to convert block to minutes. So I think each block is 2 minutes (am I right?). I want to multiply all numbers in the first column by 2 whose unit is block. Here is an example:

```
TOBUS     TOBUSU
  2     (1) Block
  3      (1) Block
  5        minutes
  4       (1) Block
  2        minutes
```

In above example I will have

```
TOBUS     TOBUSU
  4       minutes
  6        minutes
  5        minutes
  8        minutes
  2        minutes
```

Comment: `with(df, ifelse(TOBUSU != 'minutes', TOBUS * 2, TOBUS))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the number between round bracket and multiply with `TOBUS`

```
vals <- df$TOBUS * as.integer(sub("\\((\\d+)\\).*", "\\1", df$TOBUSU)) * 2
df$TOBUS[!is.na(vals)] <- vals[!is.na(vals)]
df$TOBUSU <- "minutes"

df
#  TOBUS  TOBUSU
#1     4 minutes
#2     6 minutes
#3     5 minutes
#4     8 minutes
#5     2 minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be:

```
# df is your data.frame
df$TOBUS[df$TOBUSU=="(1) Block"] <- df$TOBUS[df$TOBUSU=="(1) Block"] * 2
df$TOBUSU[df$TOBUSU=="(1) Block"] <- "minutes"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$TOBUS <- ifelse(df$TOBUSU == "(1) Block", df$TOBUS * 2, df$TOBUS)
df$TOBUSU <- "minutes"

#Output
TOBUS  TOBUSU
4      minutes
6      minutes
5      minutes
8      minutes
2      minutes
```